# Where do we keep the website configuration file in yii?

Tags: yii

I want some information and settings are stored in the location Yii that I have access to it in anywhere of the program(controller,view,model .....)
Can i create this file as Component or Extension?
my another question:
How can I create a function that will auto run on all pages?(global function).

Comment: read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the application is set up and there might be more of them.

Usually you can find it in protected/config/.

Link to how to use it http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/59/.